# converting dataframe columns from matrix to vector

Tags: r

I'm trying to combine a few dataframes. In the process of doing so, I noticed that one dataframe contains matrices rather than vectors. Here's a basic example:

```
df3 <- structure(list(v5 = structure(c(NA, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("206", "207"), "ecbi1")), v6 = structure(c(NA, 0), .Dim = c(2L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(c("206", "207"), "ecbi2"))), .Names = c("v5", 
"v6"), row.names = 206:207, class = "data.frame")

# get class
class(df3[,1])
# [1] "matrix"
```

I want the columns in `df3` to be vectors, not matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just apply as.vector

```
df3[] = lapply(df3, as.vector)
```

Comment: See? You don't always have to `library(dplyr/tidyr)` and then `spread %>% gather %>% mutate %>% another_irrelevant_function`...

Answer (score 3):

I think most important is to figure out how you managed to get `matrix`-type columns in the first place and understand whether this was a desired behavior or a side effect of a mistake somewhere earlier.

Given where you are, you can just use `c` to undo a given column:

```
df3$v5 <- c(df3$v5)
```

Or if this is a problem with all columns:

```
df3[ ] <- lapply(df3, c)
```

(`lapply` returns a `list` of vectors, and when we pass a `list` via assignment to a `data.frame`, it interprets each list element as a column; `df3[ ]` returns all columns of `df3`. We could also do `df3 <- lapply(df3, c)`, but using `[ ]` is more robust -- if we make a mistake and somehow return the wrong number of columns, an error will be thrown, where as simply using `df3` would have simply overwritten our `data.frame` silently in case of such an error)

Lastly, if only some columns are `matrix`-type, we can replace only those columns like so:

```
mat.cols <- sapply(df3, is.matrix)
df3[ , mat.cols] <- lapply(df3[ , mat.cols], c)
```

As pertains to the relation between this approach and that using `as.vector`, from `?c`:

> `c` is sometimes used for its side effect of removing attributes except names, for example to turn an array into a vector. `as.vector` is a more intuitive way to do this, but also drops names.

So given that the names don't mean much in this context, `c` is simply a more concise approach, but the end result is practically identical.

Answer (score 1):

Use this.

```
df3[,1] = as.vector(df3[,1])
```

The same procedure can be applied generally to the rest of the columns.

Comment: @bramtayl's solution is exactly a better version of this.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `do.call`

```
do.call(data.frame, df3)
```